# Laravel 5: "Base table or view not found" Table X "doesn't exist" - laravel is confusing virtual hosts

Tags: mysql, database, apache, laravel, virtualhost

Getting this error message RANDOMLY while nav'ing to my view:

QueryException in Connection.php line 636:SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'salesspacetv.devices' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `devices` inner join `statustypes` on `devices`.`status` = `statustypes`.`num` inner join `aggservers` on `devices`.`aggserver_num` = `aggservers`.`num` left join `tickets` on `devices`.`id` = `tickets`.`device_id` group by `devices`.`id`) in Connection.php line 636

- My server uses multiple virtual hosts, defined in c:\apache24\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.
- "c1.[ourcompanyname].net" is the name of the site whose view I'm nav'ing to.
- "salesspacetv.[ourcompanyname].net" is another virtual host (running laravel) on our server.
- The word "salesspacetv" absolutely does not exist anywhere in c1's code.
- "devices" IS a table used by the c1 site, and there is no "devices" table used by the salesspacetv site.

It seems like laravel's base code is making use somewhere of what it thinks is the subdomain name and that Apache (fyi... running on Windows, on this server) is somehow not getting the correct subdomain name to laravel.

Again, this is a random error.  If I simply refresh the page, the error goes away.  Also note, whether important or not, that this view is using pagination.  I don't imagine that has any importance, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

The databases are MySQL databases.

Lastly, the c1 virtual host definition does actually appear before the salesspacetv virtual host definition in httpd-vhosts.conf.

Thanks.

Comment: could you post laravel logs (in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`) perhaps it can show some insight. i wonder how come you get the conclusion that the query fails caused by virtual host - which kind of unrelated. personally i suspect it had something to do to your configuration (either `.env` or `/config/database.php`).

Comment: Thanks very much.  I have a 56 line chunk of laravel.log pertaining to this... best way to post here w/o overflowing past the character limit?

Comment: well, perhaps you could use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). anyway give a shot for the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I ran into this error in the past when I was dealing with multiple projects in my local environment.

Let me get this straight, you are using 1 project then whenever it is involving a database table call it sometimes references to a table or column name that the current project does not contain but contains in another project?

If that is what's happening to you, how I fixed it on my end was name your database environments (.env file) different per project.

**#1 .env Method**

.env

Project 1:

```
DB_PROJECT1_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_PROJECT1_DATABASE=dbname
DB_PROJECT1_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PROJECT1_PASSWORD=dbpass
```

Project 2:

```
DB_PROJECT2_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_PROJECT2_DATABASE=dbname
DB_PROJECT2_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PROJECT2_PASSWORD=dbpass
```

app\config\database.php

Project 1:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_PROJECT1_HOST'),
    'database'  => env('DB_PROJECT1_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_PROJECT1_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PROJECT1_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Project 2:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_PROJECT2_HOST'),
    'database'  => env('DB_PROJECT2_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_PROJECT2_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PROJECT2_PASSWORD'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Hopefully this is the same issue happening to you so you can quickly test this and see if it applies to you.

**#2 Alternative (hardcode method suggested by Tezla):**

You may also edit the database configuration file (app\config\database.php) and hardcode the database information directly to avoid configuration leaks:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '0.0.0.0',
    'database'  => 'dbname',
    'username'  => 'dbuser',
    'password'  => 'dbpass',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
]
```

Comment: That looks very cool.  I'm not well-versed enough with Laravel to know how the .env files could get twisted, but I followed your instructions (put in "C1" for "PROJECT1"  in the 4 Project 1 vbls above in C1's .database.php file, then adjusted the 4 lines in C1's .env file to match those vbl names.  Works great so far, will let you know if I see the error.  Thank you VERY much, guys.         For future ref. (I'm such a noob)... how to format these comments with carriage returns, etc., like I did in my orig post, and how to post attachments or large code chunks?  Thanks again!

Comment: alternatively, you could simply **hardcode** configurations to `/app/config` to avoid configuration leak which rarely happen.

Comment: @J.Martin Read here: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet